# ERROR 1064 (42000) while importing .sql file into MySQL

Tags: import, mysql

I'm trying to import a client's database dump into my MySQL 5.5.27 (for Win64) running on Windows Vista 64 bit. However, I get

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 24: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*/'
>   at line 8

I've pasted the first several lines of the dump file below:

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `foobar` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `foobar`;
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.16, for osx10.5 (i386)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: foobar
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.21

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Temporary table structure for view `reference`
--

CREATE TABLE `reference` (
  `xyz` varchar(50),
  `ABC` varchar(50),
  `asdf` varchar(50),
  `abcd` varchar(7),
  `Axe` varchar(255),
  `Age` varchar(255)
) ENGINE=MyISAM */;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

Comment: The script is not complete. Take a look at two last lines.

Comment: Are you referring to the */ after MyISAM? That's puzzling to me, but I'm new to SQL itself so thought it might make some sense to experienced people. Does this mean someone manually tinkered with the dump before sending it in? This extract is from the beginning of the dump file, I haven't removed any lines at the beginning.

Comment: It seems this is a beginning of commented code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the script in this way -

```
...
CREATE TABLE `reference` (
  `xyz` varchar(50),
  `ABC` varchar(50),
  `asdf` varchar(50),
  `abcd` varchar(7),
  `Axe` varchar(255),
  `Age` varchar(255)
) ENGINE=MyISAM */;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;*/
```

or just remove that part -

```
...
CREATE TABLE `reference` (
  `xyz` varchar(50),
  `ABC` varchar(50),
  `asdf` varchar(50),
  `abcd` varchar(7),
  `Axe` varchar(255),
  `Age` varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: I tried both of these alternatives, but both give the same error as in the question. Why do you think this is a *beginning* of commented code? */ is a comment terminator, is it not? 
Thanks for attempting a solution by the way.

Comment: Ohhh, yes; it is '*/'. So it is not a start of comment. But the second CRETE TABLE is working.